# scrapy Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

Tags: python, scrapy

I find it can't run `short_critic_content(self,response)` why, I can't find reason.

I didn't use `allowed_domains`, 
if I take it,  the `short_critic_content(self,response)` is don't run.

`allowed_domains = ["movie.mtime.com"].`

`start_urls = ['http://movie.mtime.com']` is wrong or right!

What's wrong with it getting error :

> Scrapy Unsupported URL scheme '': no handler available for that scheme

```html
class YinPin(CrawlSpider):
    name = "yingping"
    #allowed_domains = ["movie.mtime.com"]

    start_urls = ['http://movie.mtime.com']

    rules = (
        #Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=())),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://movie.mtime.com/40677/'), ), callback='movie_info', follow=False),
    )

    def movie_info(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        #for movieinfo in movie_info:
        movie_name = selector.xpath('//*[@id="db_head"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/h1/text()').extract()
        movie_url = response.url#movieinfo.xpath('//*[@id="db_head"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]/@href').extract()
        number = re.compile(r'\d+')
        movie_num = int(number.search(str(movie_url)).group())

        movie_release_time = selector.xpath('//*[@id="db_head"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p[1]/a/text()').extract()
        movie_place = selector.xpath('//*[@id="db_head"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/text()').extract()[3]
        movie_type = selector.xpath('//*[@id="db_head"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a/text()').extract()
        movie_type_l = movie_type.pop()
        movie_type = ' '.join(movie_type)


        short_content = selector.css('#tweetRegion > dd > div > h3::text').extract()  # selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetRegion"]').css('h3::text').extract()
        short_url = str(selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetBottomDiv"]/p[2]/a/@href').extract())
        yield Request(short_url, callback=self.short_critic_content,
                      meta={ 'movie_num': movie_num,
                            'short_content': short_content})
        item = YingpingItem(
            movie_num = movie_num,
            movie_name = movie_name,
            movie_release_time = movie_release_time,
            movie_place = movie_place,
            movie_type = movie_type,
        )
        yield item

    def short_critic_content(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        movie_num = response.meta['movie_num']
        short_contentft = response.meta['short_content']
        short_contentsd = selector.css('#tweetRegion > dd > div > h3::text').extract()
        short_contents = short_contentft +short_contentsd

        item = shortcriticItem(
            movie_num = movie_num,
            movie_scritic = short_contents
        )
        yield  item
```

Comment: This most probably is the case of relative urls. The value of `short_url` will have a relative url instead of having a full url. You can try using `yield response.follow(short_url, callback=self.short_critic_content,
                      meta={ 'movie_num': movie_num,
                            'short_content': short_content})`

Comment: short_ url  is http://movie.mtime.com/246560/reviews/short/new.html ,it is a full url

Comment: selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetBottomDiv"]/p[2]/a/@href')[0].extract()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certain the problem is in this line of your `movie_info` function:

```
short_url = str(selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetBottomDiv"]/p[2]/a/@href').extract())
```

`extract()` method of `Selector` returns a list, which you then convert to string. But that won't give you the URL, it gives you a string representation of the list, which starts with `"` character. That's why you get that error.

The correct way is either

```
short_url = selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetBottomDiv"]/p[2]/a/@href').extract()[0]
```

or even better to use `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`

```
short_url = selector.xpath('//*[@id="tweetBottomDiv"]/p[2]/a/@href').extract_first()
```